# Stack multiple columns with different headers into two columns?

Tags: excel, csv, multiple-columns

I have a number of csv sheets that have data in the following format:

A B C D
1 x y z
2 j k l
3 f g h

etc.

I need it to look like:

A B
1 x
1 y
1 z
2 j
2 k
2 l
3 f
3 g
3 h
etc.

I have this for many csv sheets, and each sheet has different headers and a different number of columns. Any tips would be SO helpful as I'm totally stuck! Thanks!

Comment: Can you put up screen shots of your documents and show us what you have already tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with Excel and want to manipulate that data, then there will likely be no better option than to use VBA.  It's built in and very robust.  If needed, you can call Windows library functions as well as a plethora of others.  Exporting any programmatic manipulations would be trivial.

You can write the code into a *.bas file and import the code into each workbook.  Or if it's all in the same workbook, you can simply create a module that all sheets can reference.  You can even programmatically walk through all the sheets.

It is difficult to give you specific ideas since I don't know specifically what you are trying to do, however if you are simply trying to concatenate all the fields (columns) into one, you can simply insert a column ("B", I'm assuming), and enter =CONCAT(C1:Z1) (just an example) to put all the values together.  Once done, you can copy that column and paste the values into a new column and then delete everything else you don't want.

You could even do all of the above in VBA.  Some simple VBA to exemplify the idea.  Note that the formula line below will put the formula in ALL cells of column B.  This probably isn't what you want, but I'll leave it to you to Google finding the end of your data.

```
Public Sub ConcatColumns()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        ws.Columns(2).Insert
        ws.Columns(2).Formula = "=CONCAT(C1:Z1)"
    Next ws
End Sub
```